# Visual Studio 2015 Tries installing Glyphfriend every time I start Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I tried installing the extension Glyphfriend in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, after downloading it and installing, it asked me to restart Visual Studio and now every time I start Visual Studio it re-installs Glyphfriend and asks me to restart Visual Studio.  My thought is that there must be some sort of cache or temp file somewhere prompting the installation every time upon start-up.  Any help would be really appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: According to your description, I download the extension named Glyphfriend, and I have not encounter the issue. please click Tools --> Extensions and Updates --> Tools --> select Glyphfriend 2015 --> uninstall. And then download the lasted version, and install again.

Comment: I have literally tried everything short of uninstalling Visual Studio.  I have uninstalled the extension and reinstalled it, I did an installation repair of Visual Studio, cleared cache and temp files, I really do not know what to do at this point.  Might just have to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio itself.  Thank you for the reply btw.

Comment: please check the following option. 1. install other extension tools and check if it works. 2. check if you use administers user login your machine. 3. please run visual studio 2015 as administer and install it again and check if works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I figured out whatvwas happening.  So I installed Glyphfriend first, and then installed the Web Extension Pack extension which apparently also includes Glyphfriend.  So something was obviously clashing there.  So I uninstalled both extensions and re-installed the Web Extension Pack and it solved the issue.  Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: I am glad to know you solved this problem and thanks for sharing the solution. please mark it as answer, it will be very beneficial for other community members who have the similar questions.